# Convert datetimeoffset in varchar to date / datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure db where we have a varchar columns with date and time info in the format:

```
2019-11-04T16:25:15.000+0000
```

I've tried converting it to datetime time using  `cast(createddate as datetimeoffset)` but I get the error;

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Tried `datetimeoffset(2)` to (7) but same error occurs.

UPDATE: Another query,
Is there a way to format a varchar column with different date time formats coming in?
I have these values in col1
 2019-11-04T16:25:15.000+0000
 2019-11-05T15:17:06+00:00
 **CONVERT(datetimeoffset, REPLACE(createddate, '+', 0))** works for 2019-11-04T16:25:15.000+0000
  and
 **CONVERT(datetimeoffset, createddate)** works for 2019-11-05T15:17:06+00:00

Is there a function which could work for both and other date formats as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the +0000 section of your string is supposed to represent the timezone offset, it is malformed as far as cast/datetimeoffset is concerned.

It should be in the format +hh:mm - if i try casting 2019-11-04T16:25:15.000+00:00, it works fine.

MS SQL reference here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

*Update*: incorporating SalmanA's comments:

```
select 
    CAST('2019-11-04 16:25:15+09:00' AS datetimeoffset(7)) as [No T],
    CAST('2019-11-04T16:25:15+09:00' AS datetimeoffset(7)) as [With T]
```

returns (in SQL 2016)

```
[No T]                               [With T]
2019-11-04 16:25:15.0000000 +09:00   2019-11-04 16:25:15.0000000 +09:00
```

showing that the T being present or not doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, it is malformed. Im not sure what format this is 2019-11-04T16:25:15.000+0000

Comment: It _could_ be +/- integer minutes, but as I understand it, that's not a standard format that SQL recognises.

Comment: `2019-11-04T16:25:15.000+0000` format is part of ISO 8601 standard.

Comment: @tkay141 no, you'll have to replace `T` with a space and insert a `:` between `+0000` to make it acceptable datetimeoffset.

Comment: A quick experiment in MS SQL 2016 suggests that the T can stay in place, but the : character must split the hh and mm elements of the time zone designator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` :

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetimeoffset, REPLACE(col, '+', 0))
```